# Get php array from jquery serialize function sended value

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I make a AJAX call, and sends the argument equal to forms's serialize-d value.

```
var form_data= $('#some-form').serialize();
var data = {
                    action: 'my-action',
                    data: form_data
                };
$.post(my-file.php,data...){...}
```

So in my php file var I have a `$_POST['data'] = arg1=value1&arg2[arg2_1]=value2...` and so on.

It can be a long string with unlimited number of arguments **and unlimited depth level**.

So the question - is there any function in php, to make such string to an Associative array like this

```
$my_post[arg1]=value1;
$my_post[arg_2][arg2_1]=value2;
...
```

Or I need to write that function myself?

Comment: Does that question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003122/php-unserialize-jquery-form-post

Comment: Unfortunately - no. I have to send the data exactly by described way.

Comment: What prevents you from doing it the way suggested in the other question?

Comment: It is the piece of WordPress plugin, so the WordPress core structure prevents me :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $my_post);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str) as described here: [PHP unserializing a JS serialized string of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064529/php-unserializing-a-js-serialized-string-of-variables)